# Regular Expression optional matches without greediness

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

For educational purposes, I'm trying to match name, phone and email of the following content:

```
John
+1 288298600
john@site.com

Billy

Mike
+1 768397651
mike@site.com

Patrick
+2 938468172

Jack
jack@site.com
```

I know how to get all emails and all phones from that, but what I want to do here is different.

I want to get, for each name (John, Billy, Mike, Patrick, Jack) their phone (if any) and their email (if any). So matches would be like

```
'John',    '+1 288298600',  'john@site.com'
'Billy',   '',             ''
'Mike',    '+1 768397651', 'mike@site.com'
'Patrick', '+2 93868172',  ''
'Jack',    '',             'jack@site.com'
```

Notice that if there is no corresponding info (phone or email) it matches an empty string. How can I do that?

My attempt: `([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:.*?(\+.*?)|.*?)(?:.*?(.*?\@site.com)|.*?)`

Anyone can guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Show your attempts

Comment: Updated with my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to do this using multiple matches, it won't lead you anywhere. Instead, match one time per entry, and use capturing groups to extract relevant data.

Here's an example (with the `mx` flags):

```
^(?<name>[\p{L}\h]+$)\R
(?:(?<phone>^\+[\d\h]+$)\R)?
(?<mail>^.+?@.+?\..+)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS2kO4/1)

The first line matches the name, followed by a newline. The second line is optional - it matches a phone number, followed by a newline. The third line, also optional, matches the mail.

You may refine the subpatterns if needed, I just picked some which seemed to work with your input data.

Comment: How do I know if a phone/mail belongs to a specific name? Assuming that phone/mail is optional, it means that its matches might be fewer than the (mandatory) names. Thanks. (PS: do you mean I should run preg_match 3 times?)

Comment: Check the demo link. This is a **single** regex. You can write it in one line like so: `^(?<name>[\p{L}\h]+$)\R(?:(?<phone>^\+[\d\h]+$)\R)?(?<mail>^.+?@.+?\..+)?` but it's less readable. So each match will bring you 1 to 3 pieces of info. Use it with `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. How would you solve this without any modifiers? I am trying to port it to C++ (TR1 regex) aswell.

Comment: Uh, oh - you should have said that in the first place, as `std::regex` is *severely* more limited than PCRE. I'd rather recommend `boost::regex` if you can (or even PCRE itself, but it has a C API). So put everything into a single line, replace the first `^` with `(?:^|\r?\n)`, remove all the other `^` and `$` from the pattern, and replace all `\R` with `\r?\n`. That *should* work with `std::regex`, but really, use something better if you can.